# Java Using Rand Access File To Get certain Characters From File

Tags: java

Using random file access, read the last name and Major of each record and write out to a sequential file.  Display these records on the screen. Where i am stuck is trying to get the raf.seek to stop only on certain  characters so i know for the data to show up i have to find the characters 7-18  and characters 34-50. I am also wondering if it would be easier if I turn that file into a string an go from there?

Example data file

nnnnnnaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbb939ccccccccccccccccc

125546Jones          Bob     045Computer Science
334535Brown          Steve   023Chemistry
227863Finklestein    Ruddy   056History
443456Howler         Iain    038Computer Science
883643Morrison       Tony    045Physics

*Output file*

Jones         Computer Science

Brown         Chemistry

Finklestein   History

Howler        Computer Science

Morrison      Physics

*The screen will also show:*

Jones         Computer Science

Brown         Chemistry

Finklestein   History

Howler        Computer Science

Morrison      Physics

Here Is What I Have so Far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RandomAccessFileDemo {

    private static void doAccess() {

        try {

            File file = new File("myfile.txt");
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

            // Read a character
            byte ch = raf.readByte();
            System.out.println("Read first character of file: " + (char)ch);
            System.out.println("Read full line: " + raf.readLine());
            raf.seek(4);
            System.out.println("Read line 4: " + raf.readLine());
            // Seek to the end of file
            raf.seek(file.length());

            // Append to the end of the file
            raf.write(0x0A);
            raf.writeBytes("This will complete the Demo");
            raf.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doAccess();
    }

}
```

Comment: `raf.seek(4);
            System.out.println("Read line 4: " + raf.readLine());` **FAIL**

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         System.out.println("Read full line: " + raf.readLine());
>         raf.seek(4);
>         System.out.println("Read line 4: " + raf.readLine());
> ```

The seek method of`RandomAccessFile` does not move the offset by number of lines it moves it in terms of bytes.

Here's an extract from:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/randomaccessfile_seek.htm

> **pos** -- the offset position, measured in bytes from the beginning of the file, at which to set the file pointer.

So you will need to calculate the number of bytes by which to move the file pointer and then read the record.

I suggest you to use `readLine` inside a loop and the parse each line to extract the data you need.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the file  line by line with a while loop (while you don't get end of file, read next line) . In each iteration you may turn the line to string, then  analize that line and print that what you are interested on.

This is a typical file analyzer.